# How do I add data dynamically into an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic, for-loop

I want to add new data to an array dynamically using HTML and PHP

Here is my code:

```
<form action="" method="">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" name="send">
</form>

   <?php
   if(isset($_POST['send']))
   {
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     for($=1;$i<2;$++)
     {
     $name = array($name);
     $names = array_push($names,$name);
     }
     print_r($names);
   }
  ?>`
```

Does anyone have a better way?

Comment: Since your script is executed once it was requested, all data in it will be destroyed after it was executed. To store data between several requests, use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to create indexes after its declaration:

```
$test = array();
$test['a'] = 'value';
$test['b'] = 'value';
$test['c'] = 'value';
```